# mysql workbench not exporting data with utf8

Tags: sql, utf-8, mysql-workbench, mysql

I have a database encoded in utf8 and I want to export it to a dump file. The problem is that when I do it the data in the dump file are not encoded in utf8. Is there a way to define the encoding when creating the dump file ?

Answer (score 0):

Your DB when you created it, may have been using another form of encoding aside from UTF8. You may want to refer to this article about how to change encoding settings. Hopefully once that has been changed you will be able to export.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-applications.html

This doc will show you how to encode per table, as well as how to change your encoding via CLI.

Cheers.